# Prove that $(n+1)a\leq a^{n+1}+n, \forall a,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

We can start from the fact that:
\begin{align*}
    0\leq a^n + a^{n-1} +\ldots + a^2 + a-n,\forall a,n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{align*}
The above is true, since if $a>1$, then $a^n>n, \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$. Also if $a = 1$, then we will have $1 + 1 + \ldots + 1 + 1-n = n-n = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus we have:
\begin{align*}
    0 &\leq (a^{n} + a^{n-1} + \ldots + a^2 + a-n)(a-1)\\
    0 &\leq (a^{n} + a^{n-1} + \ldots + a^2 + a)(a-1)-n(a-1)\\
    0 &\leq a(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \ldots + a + 1)(a-1) -na + n\\
    0 &\leq a(a^{n}-1) -na + n\\
    0 &\leq a^{n + 1} -a-na + n\\
    0 &\leq a^{n + 1} -(n + 1) a + n\\
    (n + 1)a &\leq a^{n + 1} + n\\
\end{align*}

Another form of reason is using the inequality of the arithmetic mean with the geometric mean, as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{a^{n + 1} + n}{n + 1} &= \frac{a^{n + 1} + 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1 + 1}{n + 1}\\
                          &\geq \sqrt[n + 1]{a^{n + 1}(1)(1)\ldots(1)(1)}\\
                          &= \sqrt[n + 1]{a^{n + 1}}\\
                          & = a.
\end{align*}
Finally it is solved and we have $a^{n + 1} + n \geq (n + 1)a$.

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.

Comment: Can you explain why the first line is true if $ 0 < a < 1$? Or are you assuming that $a$ is an integer (which isn't stated in the question)?

Comment: Yes, I am only considering positive integers, as the statement indicates.

Comment: Ah. In which case, I encourage you to check the source to see if the "$\forall a, n \in \mathbb{N}$" truly wants $a$ to be a positive integer. This is because the inequality is true for all non-negative real $a$, which your AM-GM solution shows.

Comment: This is precisely how the statement is, that is why I put the two solutions because one is more general than the other, in any case I think that does not affect the solution, if we are only taking positive integers.

Comment: That is what you posted as [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185182/42969) to a now deleted question, isn't it? And the second solution is what Michael Rozenberg posted [as answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185204/42969) to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x)=x^{n+1}-(n+1)x+n$. Note that $f(1)=0$ and $f'(x)=(n+1)(x^n-1)$. Therefore, $f'(x)$ takes negative values in $(0,1)$ and positive values in $(1,\infty)$, as desired. So $f(x)$ takes its minimum value (which is zero) at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to solve it, by Taylor series for $a^x$, we have:
\begin{align*}
a^x\geq 1+x.
\end{align*}
As long as $a>1$. Now if $x = y-1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
a^{y-1}&\geq 1+(y-1)=y\\
a^{y-1}&\geq y\\
a^{y}&\geq ya
\end{align*}
Thus, if $y = n+1$,
\begin{align*}
n+a^{n+1}\geq a^{n+1}\geq (n+1)a.
\end{align*}
Finally for $ a = 1 $ we have trivially.

Comment: $1.1^2<1+2,2^{1/2}<1+1/2$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the result follows from the [Bernoulli’s inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality):

$$[1+(a-1)]^{n+1}\geq 1+(n+1)(a-1),$$ which is true for all real numbers $a\geq 0$, and all integers $n\geq -1$. (Exclude the case when $a=0,n=-1$ if necessary to avoid the ambiguity $0^0$.)