# On the conjectured inequality $q > k$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with *special/Eulerian prime* $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds. ([Beasley (2013), page 25 - third paragraph](https://pillars.taylor.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1010&context=acms-2013))

I recently came across the following question:
[Prove that $(n+1)a\leq a^{n+1}+n, \forall a,n\in\mathbb{N}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187115)

Note that, specializing to $a = q$ and $n = k$, we obtain
$$q^{k+1} + k \geq (k + 1)q$$
$$q^{k+1} - 1 \geq (k + 1)(q - 1)$$
$$\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1} \geq k + 1$$
$$k + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k),$$
where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

---

**Edit: December 27, 2021 - 1:00 PM - Manila time**

Since equality occurs in
$$(n+1)a \leq a^{n+1}+n$$
if and only if $a=1$, then equality **does not occur** in
$$k + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k),$$
since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$, so that what we actually have is the inequality
$$k + 1 < \sigma(q^k).$$

---

In particular, note that when $k=1$, we get
$$k + 1 < \sigma(q^k) = q + 1,$$
which implies that $q > k$.  (**Sanity check:** If $k=1$, then since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have $q \geq 5 > 1 = k$.)

Notice that it is true in general that
$$q + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k).$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Will it be possible to remove the reliance of the proof for the inequality $q > k$ on the condition $k=1$?  That is, do we unconditionally have
> $$k + 1 < q + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k)?$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose to the contrary that $q < k$.  Then we obtain
$$q + 1 < k + 1 < \sigma(q^k)$$
which implies that $k \neq 1$.  (More is actually true.  A similar reasoning via the starting point $k > q$ proves the following: Since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $k > q$ implies that $k > q \geq 5$, which implies that $k > 5$, from which it follows that $k \geq 9$.)

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

I currently do not see a way to derive a contradiction between the assumption $q < k$ and the known result $k + 1 < \sigma(q^k)$.

---

Elsewhere, various authors (Cohen and Sorli, and then Robbins) have ruled out values for $q$ such that $q = k$.  I then dare to conjecture that:

> **CONJECTURE:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $q \neq k$.

**Alas, I have no proof for this Conjecture.**

---

**REFERENCES**

```
    Sorli, R. M., & Cohen, G. L. (2012). On odd perfect numbers and even 3-perfect numbers, Integers, 12A, Article #A6.

    Robbins, N. (2013). On the Eulerian factor of an odd perfect number, Universal Journal of Mathematics and Mathematical Sciences, 4 (2), 237–239.
```

Comment: FYI, one can get $\sigma(q^k)\geqslant k+5$ which is better than $\sigma(q^k)\gt k+1$ since $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial k}\bigg(\sigma(q^k)-k-1\bigg)\gt 0$ and $\sigma(q^k)-k-1\geqslant (q+1)-2\geqslant 4$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Please write out your last comment as an actual answer, so that I can upvote it. =)

Answer (score 2):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

FYI, one can get $\sigma(q^k)\geqslant k+5$ which is better than $\sigma(q^k)\gt k+1$ since $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial k}\bigg(\sigma(q^k)-k-1\bigg)\gt 0$$ and $$\sigma(q^k)-k-1\geqslant (q+1)-2\geqslant 4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967)'s hint, I can get the following derivation:

---

Suppose that
$$\sigma(q^k) \geqslant k+5,$$
which we know to be true as obtained by mathlove in the comments.

Set
$$f(k):= \sigma(q^k) - k - 5 \geqslant 0.$$

Then, since
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial k}\Bigg(\sigma(q^k) - k - 5\Bigg)=\frac{\partial }{\partial k}\Bigg(\sigma(q^k) - k - 1\Bigg) = \frac{q(q^k \ln(q) - 1) + 1}{q - 1} > 0,$$
then we know that $f(k)$ is an *increasing* function of $k$.  In particular, we obtain
$$f(k) = \sigma(q^k) - k - 5 \geqslant f(1) = (q + 1) - 6 = q - 5$$
from which we get
$$\sigma(q^k) \geqslant q + k,$$
which finally yields
$$\sigma(q^k) \geqslant q + k \geqslant k + 5,$$
thus showing that mathlove's bound *cannot* be significantly improved in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment converted into an answer**

---

A better bound for $\sigma(q^k)$ is as follows:
$$\sigma(q^k) \geqslant q^k + 1 \geqslant q + k,$$
where the second inequality
$$q^k + 1 \geqslant q + k$$
holds for all primes $q$ satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and all positive integers $k$ such that $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.